# Textbox.text returns empty string in code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog, popup

I have 2 textboxes on the modal, but this one wont show the value in code behind.
This is Modal popup.

```
<div id="travelo-login" class="travelo-login-box travelo-box">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="input-text full-width"
            placeholder="User Name"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="input-text full-width" TextMode="Password"
            placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="User name or Password is incorrect" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogin" OnClientClick="SetUserInfo();" runat="server" CssClass="button btn-large green full-width"
            Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="#" class="forgot-password pull-right">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is code behind

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUserName1.Text == "admin" && txtPassword1.Text == "admin")
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```

These textbox always returns empty.

Comment: I feel like you might be reseting the txtbox as empty in Page_Load() evnet, can you show your code of Page_Load() event.

Comment: textbox.text is not used in Page_Load()

Comment: what this javascript `OnClientClick="SetUserInfo();"` code do ?

Comment: function SetUserInfo() {

                                    var txtUserName1 = document.getElementById("txtUserName1");
                                    var txtPassword1 = document.getElementById("txtPassword1");
                                    var hfUserName = document.getElementById("hfUserName");
                                    var hfPassword = document.getElementById("hfPassword");

                                    hfUserName.value = txtUserName1.value;
                                    hfPassword.value = txtPassword1.value;